# Load jquery Ui Scripts in asp.net applications

Tags: asp.net, jquery, jquery-ui, load

is there any component or control exist for asp.net application that load jquery ui scripts and themes?
thanks.
Depend on [this](http://hasheminezhad.com/sites/default/files/hasheminezhad.com/JQControls-Source.zip) sample Can Any body help me and introducing component or control ? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this sample source maybe useful :)
its created for jquery datepicker.
http://hasheminezhad.com/sites/default/files/hasheminezhad.com/JQControls-Source.zip

Answer (score 1):

hmm - couldn't you just have them included in your masterpage and then they'd be on every page referenced (by that master) on the site??

this is how i'd do it if you wanted to keep it simple. if you're looking for a control to do this, then you could of course create a usercontrol and place that in the head section of your masterpage to effectively do the same thing.

that said, maybe i've missed something here :)

Comment: look this http://hasheminezhad.com/sites/default/files/hasheminezhad.com/JQControls-Source.zip

Answer (score 1):

There aren't that I'm aware of...though it wouldn't be too hard to fashion.  Do you need one though?  Using the Google cdn for example, all you need is this in your master page:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.5/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
<link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.5/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

As of a few weeks ago (Sep 17, 2010) Microsoft also hosts jQuery UI:

```
<script src="http://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.8.5/jquery-ui.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
<link href="http://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.8.5/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```